# Allow Escaped Double Quote in ESAPI Validator

Tags: spring-mvc, owasp, esapi

There is a specific scenario where user provides input in inches as 12", which is sent as JSON and stored in database. This JSON is dynamic so it will not be sent as an object but as a JSON string which is handled in back-end, it appears as

```
{"value": "12\""}
```

In back-end however this string becomes

```
{"value": "12""}
```

which throws exception while parsing to JSONObject since it is not correct JSON string. I tried to escape the backslash as

```
{"value": "12\\\""}
```

but this throws multiple encoding exception.

Consider security points in mind is there a way that this quote can be sent as data?

Comment: What's the calls look like when you encode, and where you decode?  I just wrote this codec test:

`assertEquals("\\\"", codec.decode("\\\\\""));` and it works fine.  Will test higher up in the call structure.

Comment: There are definitely not enough details provided here to answer your question. I agree with @avgvstvs that we need more information.